# MS Server R2 Standard & Hyper V

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

We have a physical 2012 R2 Standard DC.
Can the Hyper-V Manager be loaded and two Virtual servers be created within the licensing of MS 2012 R2 licensing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you have only the Hyper-V's role on the physical's host, but no if you have a DC on it like you seem to have.

> If you want to have a lightly virtualized environment, you can choose
>   to run multiple instances of Windows Server by licensing Windows
>   Server 2012 R2 Standard edition. For both Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Standard and Datacenter editions, you need to license all the physical
>   processors on the server. For each license for Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Standard that you assign to a server you may run, at any one time, two
>   instances of the server software in up to two virtual OSEs on the
>   server. **If all two instances are running in virtual OSEs, you can also
>   run an instance in the physical OSE solely to run hardware
>   virtualization software, provide hardware virtualization services, or
>   run software to manage and service OSEs on the licensed server.**

From [there](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/MicrosoftServerVirtualization_LicenseMobility_VLBrief.pdf)

Comment: @Robg My pleasure, and dont forget to mark as aswered if that answered you :)